# psycopg2 cannot use the libpq.dylib produced by Mac Homebrew

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, psycopg2, libpq

I installed the Homebrew version of Postgres on OS X 10.8.5 via

```
brew install postgresql
```

And then did a `cp /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.3/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/` to add a lunchy launcher for it.

Then I pointed the ([setup.cfg](https://github.com/metaperl/vcpaste/blob/master/build-psycopg2-on-osx-with-brew/setup.cfg)) to it and typed `python setup.py build`
but then I got this error:

`ld: warning: ignoring file
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.3/lib/libpq.dylib, file was built for
unsupported file format ( 0xcf 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 3
0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture
being linked (i386):
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.3/lib/libpq.dylib`

so it seems there is something odd about the build of libpq by brew
(from the standpoint of [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/) )

Comment: Looks like psycopg2 is built 32 bit whilst libpq is 32 bit. What python are you using, the Apple one is 64 bit - it would make sense to use the one in a packageing system as one point of a packaging system is to make sure all the correct and consistent compile options are used

Comment: I'm using the apple one. Thanks I will try to get the brew one.